# Why my active rigid bodies are vibrating Continuously?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I am making a simulation where dominoes are pushing each others,So I made it with rigid body , when I made my dominoes an active rigid body object and played the animation all of the dominoes vibrate from right to left which cause some dominoes to fall before its pushed by the other.

This is the properties of all of the dominoes :

[image]

How can I prevent the Dominoes from moving until its pushed by the other ?

...

[image]

[image]

Comment: For your domino objects, try checking "Enable Deactivation" under "Rigid Body Dynamics" (visible in your first screenshot).

Comment: Are the dominos and/or floor scaled? If so, try Apply Scale on each - extreme scaling can affect the stability of the simulation. Also, try activatig the Collision Margin set to a suitably low value (to avoid noticeable gaps - but not too low) - this can also help significantly.

Answer (score 3):

One factor that can considerably affect the Rigid Body behaviour and stability is the *Scale* of the objects in the scene. Where possibly you should always Apply Scale on each of the objects after you have rescaled them. This will also ensure that it behaves appropriate to its actual size rather than it's pre-scaled size and weight.

In addition, you can drastically improve the stability of the rigid body simulation by increasing the number of *Iterations* on the Rigid Body properties panel.

[image: rigid body iterations]

The default value is 10 and this is fine for crude simulations. Higher values provide more accurate simulations  but will take longer to simulate. Increase the number of iterations until the simulation is stable. I created a test scene with a single domino and found that increasing Iterations to 500 was plenty enough to avoid jittering without significantly affecting the simulation time.