# Rigid Bodies dancing around

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have active rigid bodies on top of a passive rigid body. When I play the animation (no keyframes involved) the active rigid bodies start dancing around. See this [GIF](https://i.imgur.com/fyYMufV.gifv).

Comment: The GIF link does not work so cannot see what is actually happening.

Comment: Thank you for notifying me. I fixed it.

Comment: You could add the image using the tool in the post editor, to embed your gif into the post, helping others to understand :)

Comment: It's more than 2MB. :(

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should ensure that you have Applied Scale to each of your objects (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, select Scale). Then, you can improve the accuracy of the simulation by increasing the Steps Per Second and/or the Solver Iterations settings on the Rigid Body World panel of the scene properties. See also [Why my active rigid bodies are vibrating Continuously?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101203/29586)