# How to improve the accuracy for a rigid bodies

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

How can I keep the objects from intersecting or passing through one another in rigid body simulations?

[image: problematic rigid body simulation]

I have

- checked the normals
- applied all transforms for scale, position and rotation
- set Origin > origin to geometry
- increasing the Steps per second and Solver Iterations in the *Rigid Body World* settings (I tried with the maxima 1000 and 100)
- set collision shape to **Mesh** and tried 0.4 or 0 as margins and source to final

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R3VSiNKWK5TWL3tfe1ZYt2A8fLL8QoW1

Comment: Blender uses Bullet, which is generally a pretty capable and widely used rigid body solver, but it appears blender's integration of its collision detection is a bit lacking. From my experiments at least, it doesn't look like blender does inside/outside checks, and it also appears not to have the option for continuous collision detection. if both of these were supported, I suspect the problems you are showing would go away.

Comment: Related posts: [1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133611/30849), [2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/116970/30849)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>*<strike>Work smart, not ...</strike>*</sup>

Okay, so you realized Blender bullet solver implementation is not as strong out of the box. Therefore we have to help it out a bit.

- Reconstruct your geometry with simpler shapes. In your specific file, I could just create the crate out of 5 cubes (the walls and floor) which are then parented to the crate geometry.
  [image: simple shapes]
- Use simple rigid body shape wherever possible. I made the walls into **Box** colliders and the sphere into **Sphere** colliders.

Now, you realized, that the *Steps per Second* and *Solver Iterations* don't ensure a more stable simulation, if we just increase them. Here comes a workaround: We'll make our subframes into actual frames by slowing down the simulation and the speeding it up afterwards.

1. Scale the keyframes apart by 6. The box now moves 6 times as slow.
2. Adjust the speed of the rigid body simulation. I entered `1.0/6`.
   [image: rigid body world settings]
3. Adjust the playback speed. The fps will be `24*6` and the render steps can be 6. (Obviously the scene's end will have to be adjusted as well.)
   [image: scene settings]
4. Increase the Solver steps and Iterations as needed. I used [500, 500], as shown in the above image.

The resulting simulation is stable, although my computer can't playback a 144 fps.

[image: stable sim]

Comment: I am wondering if there will be an improvement in the future whiteout these tricks?